# Rendering problem with Lightning in Chrome

Tags: lightning, chrome, rendering

Since a few days, I am experiencing a weird rendering problem in Lightning, only in Chrome.

Two issues:

- Listview drop downs do not display -- all I see is a partial scrollbar, the actual list of list views does not show. The drop down *is* created in the DOM though, I can see the elements in the inspector, but they are transparent (see image below). Same behavior for any object, standard or custom.
- User profile menu also does not appear

Some details on my hardware and software which is most likely relevant:

- Chrome version: 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: OSX El Capitan (10.11.6)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- GPU: Intel Iris Pro

The problem occurs in all orgs. Only on Chrome though: Firefox and Safari are fine. I tried a full re-install of Chrome, to no avail.

I'm completely baffled... Any pointers would be much appreciated!

=========== Screenshot ===========
[image: List view not rendered]

Comment: The standard user interface, or just code you've written?

Comment: It's just the standard UI

Comment: Do you have any chrome plugins enabled?

Comment: I do, but I did a complete clean install of Chrome and the problem still appeared even without any plugins. Same thing in an Incognito window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution...

The issue was the **Use hardware acceleration when available** setting in the Chrome Advanced Settings section. Switching that off fixes the issue :-)

[image: Chrome Settings]